# Module vue-jest in the transform option was not found

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, vuejs3

The project is with Vite + Vue3 + TypeScript + Jest
This are the packages i have :

````
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.12",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.2",
    "@vue/vue3-jest": "^27.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.11.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^27.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.8.1",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.2.0",
    "vue3-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.1"
  }```
````

There is the babel.config.js

```
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'json', 'vue'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|ts)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/tests/**/*.spec.(js|ts)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setup.ts'],
};
```

And the error after i run the test is
● Validation Error:

Module vue-jest in the transform option was not found.